# Work directly with TCP/IP internet layer in Windows (Win32)

Tags: sockets, window, tcp, winsock2

I have to re-create a TCP protocol (transport layer from TCP/IP), so, I was wondering how can I access to the Internet Layer's library in Windows (it has to be that OS, I'm not allowed to use linux). Or I also i would like to know how to use another RFC in TCP

Comment: Windows implements the TCP/IP transport for you, via the [Winsock library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673.aspx).  Create a TCP socket using `socket()` or `WSASocket()`, establish a TCP connection with it using `connect()`/`WSAConnect()` or `accept()`/`WSAAccept()` (depending on which direction you are going), and then read/write protocol data as needed using `recv()`/`WSARecv()`, `send()`/`WSASend()`, etc. There are TONS of Winsock tutorials available online if you look around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Remy Lebeau, but the question is how to create a a new transport layer or modifying another one that exits (in this case TCP), and if it is possible working directly with the Internet Layer not how to use it. That means creating new kinds of sockets with its connect(), send(), receive() fuctions. Im sorry if my question wasn't well performed

Comment: well, you can implement new protocols on top of IP using Winsock by creating a [RAW socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740463.aspx) and then send/receive your own protocol headers and payloads as needed. But, to implement an actual new transport would require writing a custom [Service Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741418.aspx) for Winsock (see [About the Winsock SPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737522.aspx)).

Comment: That helps a lot. Can I find any example of Raw Sockets? Thanks in advance