# On windows, when will 'socket' call return WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER when 'WSAStartUp' has succeeded for 2.2 as requested version?

Tags: sockets, winapi, winsock2

Suppose, our client application does below:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
int     ret;
SOCKET  sock;
ret = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsa_data);
if (ret ==0) {
  sock = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP);
}
```

When will it happen that sock == INVALID_SOCKET and WSAGetLastError() would return WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER?

MS documentation for ['socket' function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) says it can return WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER when the 'service provider returned a version other than 2.2'.

i.e. Can TCP/IP transport service provider will return a version other 2.2 during 'socket' call when WSAStartUp would have succeeded for 2.2 as requested version? if yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: Practically nowadays, never. TCP and UDP are used with AF_INET and AF_INET6 (What's AF_INET8?).

Comment: Note that `WSAStartup()` can return success but have initialized a different version than requested. If you need to ensure 2.2 is actually being used, you need to validate the version that is reported in the output `WSADATA`. Read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup#remarks) in the [`WSAStartup()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) for more details.

Comment: besides what @RemyLebeau said, I suppose [`WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) implies the returned service provider version don't match the newest version Or The protocol entry could not be found for the returned service provider.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChourdakis. It was a typo and has been now corrected.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. Suppose we have checked that the version in output WSADATA is 2.2. Then, can socket function return WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER? if yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: Thanks @YangXiaoPo-MSFT. When can that happen? QOUTE  returned service provider version don't match the newest version Or The protocol entry could not be found for the returned service provider. UNQOUTE

Comment: @AbhishekJain in 20+ years of socket programming, I have never once encountered WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER. So, is it *possible*? Maybe. Is it *likely*? No

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. I understand that. We are writing an enterprise software where we need to understand each and every error, when can it come and handle it appropriately. That’s reason of asking this question. Is it relevant to us and if yes, what remedy can we suggest to user, if we get it.

Answer (score 2):

One can use the Winsock Service Provider Interface APIs to install custom service providers, for example to implement your own TCP/IP stack.

See:

- [MS Docs / Winsock / Winsock SPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-spi)
- [MS Docs / Winsock / About the Winsock SPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/about-the-winsock-spi)
- [Work directly with TCP/IP internet layer in Windows (Win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693085/work-directly-with-tcp-ip-internet-layer-in-windows-win32)

Then see the remarks under the socket docs linked by you:

> The caller of WSAStartup passes in the wVersionRequested parameter the **highest** version of the Windows Sockets specification that the application supports.

> Winsock will utilize the first available service provider that supports the requested combination of address family, socket type and protocol parameters.

So if you (or some other application) registered a custom service provider which *doesn't* respond with 2.2 as version, then you get that error. To remedy that, select another service provider or uninstall the incorrect (dare I say corrupt) one.

Comment: Thanks. If there is no custom service provider, can socket function return WSAEINVALIDPROVIDER? if yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?